# How can i implement multiprocessing with Pyomo?

Tags: optimization, python-multiprocessing, pyomo

I am trying to solve the optimization problem for the two-node system. Both nodes have the same number of variables and constraints but different data. I want to solve the optimization problem for both the nodes in parallel using pyomo and multiprocessing. I have explained the code below to show how I am trying to implement it. Is it the right way to do it?

My Python Code is something like this:

```py
Class opt():
  def __init__(self):
    I have initialized all variables and data.
  def createmodel(self):
    I have declared all Pyomo model parameters and Variables.
  def parallelizemodel(self):
    with Pool(processes=1) as pool:
       s0 = pool.apply_async(self.node1opt, ())
       s1 = pool.apply_async(self.node2opt, ())
  def node1opt(self):
     I have defined constraints and objective function for pyomo model.
  def node2opt(self):
     I have defined constraints and objective function for pyomo model.

This code does not run properly. It does not give me errors but does not solve the optimization problem as well.
```